# ¿Como consultar una fecha que sea posterior a una fecha dada sqlite?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

Lo que quiero hacer es que si por ejemplo en una tabla sqlite tengo los siguientes datos

formato DD/MM/YYY

```
  |   FECHA    |
  --------------
  | 06/12/2017 |
  | 24/7/2015  |
  | 2/10/2014  |
  | 13/1/2017  |
  | 06/11/2017 |
```

y al hacer una consulta que seleccione las fechas anteriores a 23/6/2016
me retorne

```
     -------------
     | 24/7/2015 |
     | 2/10/2014 |
     -------------
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la siguiente sentencia de consulta, indicando que la fecha debe ser menor a la fecha solicitada, ademas indicando el nombre de [TuTabla]

```
select FECHA from [TuTabla] where date(FECHA ) < date('2016-06-23');
```

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad porque no explica nada de lo que pusiste. por favor revisa [answer]